# How to get id's of textboxes on button click?

Tags: jquery

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><input id="txt1" type="text"></td>
<tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="txt2" type="text"></td>
<tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="txt3" type="text"></td>
<tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="txt4" type="text"></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

When i click on each text box, on a keyup event i should get id's of each textbox, what i should do.

Comment: Do you want the id of ALL textboxes when a key is pressed on ONE text box? Or only the textbox that is being typed into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("table input").keyup(function(){
  alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
<td><input id="txt1" type="text"></td>
<tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="txt2" type="text"></td>
<tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="txt3" type="text"></td>
<tr>

<tr>
<td><input id="txt4" type="text"></td>
<tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like this:

```
$('input').on('keypress',function(){//you may bind "keyup", "change", etc. event
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

See: [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr), [on](http://api.jquery.com/on),[keypress](http://api.jquery.com/keypress)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input').keyup(function(){alert($(this).attr('id'))}
```

same thing for all textboxes